# PHP $_POST getting populated, incorrectly

Tags: php, post

So I'm submitting some forms on a website, (via jQuery.post) and trying to parse the results. It works for simple things, but for my actual form Many of the values are getting populated with string zeros. So e.g. `medicalProvider=MediCo` is becoming `$_POST['medicalProvider']="0"`.

This page works fine with shorter POST strings, and it used to work fine with this exact form, but I haven't touched the config so I don't know what the problem is.

Here are the results of `readfile('php://input')` and `var_dump($_POST)`, literally the first two lines of the file:

```
// readfile('php://input'):
medicalProvider=MediCo&medicalPremium=7000&medicalOccurs=0&medicalKind=0&medicalEmpOnly=50&medicalEmpSpouse=0&medicalEmpDependant=0&medicalEmpFamily=0&medicalProvider=0&medicalPremium=0&dentalProvider=DentCo&dentalPremium=500&dentalOccurs=0&dentalKind=1&dentalEmpOnly=0&dentalEmpSpouse=2&dentalEmpDependant=0&dentalEmpFamily=0&dentalProvider=0&dentalPremium=0&longTermProvider=HappCo&longTermPremium=9000&longTermOccurs=1&longTermKind=2&longTermEmpOnly=0&longTermEmpSpouse=0&longTermEmpDependant=0&longTermEmpFamily=0&longTermProvider=0&longTermPremium=0&shortTermProvider=&shortTermPremium=&shortTermOccurs=&shortTermKind=&shortTermEmpOnly=&shortTermEmpSpouse=&shortTermEmpDependant=&shortTermEmpFamily=&shortTermProvider=&shortTermPremium=&lifeProvider=DeathCo&lifePremium=70000&lifeOccurs=1&lifeKind=4&lifeEmpOnly=80&lifeEmpSpouse=2&lifeEmpDependant=0&lifeEmpFamily=0&lifeProvider=0&lifePremium=0
//var_dump($_POST):
array(40) {
  ["medicalProvider"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["medicalPremium"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["medicalOccurs"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["medicalKind"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["medicalEmpOnly"]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["medicalEmpSpouse"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["medicalEmpDependant"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["medicalEmpFamily"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dentalProvider"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dentalPremium"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dentalOccurs"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dentalKind"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["dentalEmpOnly"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dentalEmpSpouse"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["dentalEmpDependant"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dentalEmpFamily"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["longTermProvider"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["longTermPremium"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["longTermOccurs"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["longTermKind"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["longTermEmpOnly"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["longTermEmpSpouse"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["longTermEmpDependant"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["longTermEmpFamily"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["shortTermProvider"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermPremium"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermOccurs"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermKind"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermEmpOnly"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermEmpSpouse"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermEmpDependant"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["shortTermEmpFamily"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["lifeProvider"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["lifePremium"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["lifeOccurs"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["lifeKind"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["lifeEmpOnly"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["lifeEmpSpouse"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["lifeEmpDependant"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["lifeEmpFamily"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem when serving as a webpage and posting from a real form, rather than using the php://input method?

Comment: What does the html form look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

medicalProvider is being set twice.  If you have the same POST (or GET) variable more than once, it is set to the latter.

Comment: Right, that is definitely the problem. Thanks.